Reusable component for loading data
I'm Building a react/nextjs/redux app
I have components each will call an individual backend API
The issue I'm having is making the component that loads in the data more reusable there is some repetitiveness that I am hoping to get rid of
Component 1:
import { StateLoading } from "@/shared/constants/loading";

import { useSelectorEffect } from "@/hooks/useSelector";
import { getGames, selectGames, selectStatus } from "@/store/games/gamesSlice";
import { Game } from "@/shared/interfaces/game";

const GamesDisplay = () => {
  const games = useAppSelector(selectGames) as Game[];
  const isClientLoaded = useSelectorEffect(games, getGames); //custom hook below
  const isLoading = useAppSelector(selectStatus) === StateLoading.LOADING;

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading....</div>;
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div>Games Display</div>
      {isClientLoaded && (
        <ul>
          {games?.map((comic: Game) => (
            <li key={comic.id}>{comic.title}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
export default GamesDisplay;

Component 2:
import { Comic } from "@/shared/interfaces/comic";
import { StateLoading } from "@/shared/constants/loading";

import { useSelectorEffect } from "@/hooks/useSelector";

const ComicsDisplay = () => {
  const comics = useAppSelector(selectComicsArray) as Comic[];
  const isClientLoaded = useSelectorEffect(comics, getComics); //custom hook below
  const isLoading = useAppSelector(selectStatus) === StateLoading.LOADING;

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading....</div>;
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div>MusicDisplay</div>
      {isClientLoaded && (
        <ul>
          {comics?.map((comic: Comic) => (
            <li key={comic.id}>{comic.title}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
export default ComicsDisplay;

As you can see they're quite similar
custom hook:
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { useAppDispatch } from "./store.hooks";

export const useSelectorEffect = (slice: any, dispatchAction: any) => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const [isClient, setIsClient] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (slice === undefined) {
      dispatch(dispatchAction());
    }

    setIsClient(true);
  }, [slice, dispatchAction, dispatch, isClient]);

  return isClient;
};


Can you [edit] to clarify what the specific question/issue/problem is that you would like help with? If the code you have is currently working and you are looking for more of a code review then this may be a better fit for CodeReview where you are asking for optimizations.

You'll need to declare an interface for Comic and Game.
import React from "react";
import { StateLoading } from "@/shared/constants/loading";
import { useSelectorEffect } from "@/hooks/useSelector";
import { useAppSelector } from "@/store/store.hooks";

interface ReusableDisplayProps<T> {
  itemsSelector: (state: any) => T[];
  statusSelector: (state: any) => string;
  fetchAction: () => void;
  itemRenderer: (item: T) => React.ReactNode;
  title: string;
}

const ReusableDisplay = <T extends { id: string }>({
  itemsSelector,
  statusSelector,
  fetchAction,
  itemRenderer,
  title,
}: ReusableDisplayProps<T>) => {
  const items = useAppSelector(itemsSelector);
  const isClientLoaded = useSelectorEffect(items, fetchAction);
  const isLoading = useAppSelector(statusSelector) === StateLoading.LOADING;

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading....</div>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>{title}</div>
      {isClientLoaded && (
        <ul>
          {items?.map((item) => (
            <li key={item.id}>{itemRenderer(item)}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default ReusableDisplay;


Game display
const GamesDisplay = () => {
  return (
    <ReusableDisplay<Game>
      itemsSelector={selectGames}
      statusSelector={selectStatus}
      fetchAction={getGames}
      itemRenderer={(game) => game.title}
      title="Games Display"
    />
  );
};

export default GamesDisplay;

Component 2:
const ComicsDisplay = () => {
  return (
    <ReusableDisplay<Comic>
      itemsSelector={selectComicsArray}
      statusSelector={selectStatus}
      fetchAction={getComics}
      itemRenderer={(comic) => comic.title}
      title="Comics Display"
    />
  );
};

export default ComicsDisplay;


Sorry, I thought I left a comment yesterday, thank you for this it worked very well
